# Azure Web App - Create One Deploy Operation to Slot

Tags: azure, azure-webapps, azure-deployment-slots

I want to use REST API Web Apps - Create One Deploy Operation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/create-one-deploy-operation) to deploy to slot in Azure Web App.

I don't see how to do that. Has someone already faced that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*Need to check below:*

Sometimes, web applications will run out of storage capacity while being deployed to any of the slots. In this case, verify the disk space and remove the cache as well as detailed in the [blog](https://feng.lu/2017/02/23/Review-and-manage-your-web-site-space-in-Azure/) by @Feng Lu. After that, try to complete the deployment with `one deploy` operation.

Goto `Advance editor`. Open `kudu` in the browser and go to `site extensions`, search for `Disk usage`.

[image]

Add this to your environment to verify the disk usage and the available space for the deployments.

***MSDeploy operation:***

Rather than using `one deploy` operation, I would suggest you use `MSDeploy` operation as detailed below.

`One deploy` focuses primarily on simple applications. You can deploy web apps by simply uploading a zip package along with the package URL. `MSDeploy` operations work for large and complicated deployments with the specified configurations in the similar way.

*Request type:* `PUT`

*API call URL:*

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/extensions/MSDeploy?api-version=2022-03-01
```

*Request body:*

```json
{
  "kind": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "properties":{}
}
```

*Below are the required parameters to be passed:*

[image]

*Response status:*

[image]

Once it is succeeded, I checked in the `kudu files -> site extensions` and it displayed the contents as expected.

[image]

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/create-ms-deploy-operation#code-try-0) for the relevant information.

Comment: thank you for your reply. How do you specify the body with packageURI when you use MSDeploy?

Comment: There is no need of giving package URl separately when you use MSDeploy. Please check the above given MSDoc. @BertrandPons

Answer (score 0):

I actually succeeded into deploying to slot with onedeploy with the following REST API call:

az rest --method PUT --uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/resourceGroups/<RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>/slots/<SLOT_NAME>/extensions/onedeploy?api-version=2022-03-01 --body '{"properties": {"type": "zip", "packageUri": "'"<PACKAGE_URI>"'"}}'